# How do I prevent JFrame from always being on top of all other applications?

Tags: java, swing, ide, jframe, jgrasp

Before anyone asks, I have tried using `setAlwaysOnTop(false)`. Here is a repeatable example.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class SOQ_20200913
{

   public SOQ_20200913()
   {
   
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("SOQ_20200913");
      
      //for simplicity's sake, you could also comment these 2 lines - they don't seem to help or hurt the situation
      frame.setLocation(200, 200);
      frame.setSize(300, 300);
      
      frame.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
   
      frame.setVisible(true);
   
   }
   
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
   
      SOQ_20200913 stackOverflowQuestion = new SOQ_20200913();
   
   }

}
```

After I run, I click away and try to click on my code, and then my web browser, but the JFrame always remains on top.[image: Here is a visual of what I am talking about.]

Am I missing something? Is there some other field I should be setting here?

Comment: Cannot reproduce here.

Comment: That's frustrating. Do you think this might be an OS issue?

Comment: Does this occur if you run the program from a command window, with a command like `java -cp C:\some\dir SOQ_20200913`?

Comment: It does not occur when I run it on the command line! Thank you for the help! Seems the issue must be with a configuration setting on my IDE.

Comment: *"Thank you for the help!"* Tip: Add @VGR (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: @VGR much appreciated!